# Why is Serial.read() adding an extra character at the end? And how do I fix it?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, serial-communication

```cpp
char input;
 
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    delay(2000);  
 
    Serial.println("Type something!");
}
 
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        input = Serial.read();
        Serial.print("You typed:" );
        Serial.println(input);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why it is outputting it this way? It seems to be adding an extra char. I tried to search for the solution but I couldn't figure out what to search for exactly.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not typing in "something" and the hitting the enter, the enter hit might be the extra char you're seeing in the com

Answer (score 0):

Newline means adding '\n' at the end of the message.

terminating characters are helpful to know where is the end of the message.

[image: SerialMonitor]